# Hidden Features of cairngorm

Tags: apache-flex, cairngorm, flex3

I  found a lot of interesting info in the 'hidden features of...' series. I am very new to cairngorm . What are some of the hidden features of cairngorm.

Comment: What is the "Hidden Features of..' series?

Answer (score 1):

Certain pieces of Cairngorm make data binding create strong links instead of weak links. This can lead to memory leaks. I can't recall the exact place I ran into this since it was about 2 years ago. I think it might have been ModelLocator.